# How to change link based on slider input?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm creating a slider whereby a user chooses their price point of a certain object from a $500 to $10000. There are 4 different price points. 0~1000,1001~2000,2001~4000 and 4001~10000. Each different price point should go to a different link by clicking 'Take me to my ideal object!'. I am unsure of what to do in order to get the link to be updated live.

```
<div id='slidecontainer'>
      <form oninput="x.value=parseInt(tierslider.value)">
          <span>500</span>
          <input type='range' min='500' max='10000' value='500' id='tierslider'>
          <span>10000</span>
          <output id='tierslider2' name='x'></output>
      </form>
</div>

      <a href='#' id='DisplaySliderResult'>Take me to my ideal object!</a>
```

I am expecting the output link to be constantly updated based on the value such that a user can go to different websites based on their budget.

Answer (score 2):

```js
 function onRangeChanged(value) {
   let advertiseLink = document.getElementById('DisplaySliderResult');
        let url = advertiseLink.href;
        console.log(value);
        value = parseInt(value);
        switch(true) {
          case value >= 0 && value <= 1000:
            url = "link1";
            break;
          case value > 1000 && value <= 2000: 
            url= "link2";
            break;
          case value > 2000 && value <= 4000: 
            url= "link3";
            break;
          case value > 4000 && value <= 10000: 
            url= "link4";
            break;
        }
        advertiseLink.setAttribute('href', url);
        console.log(advertiseLink);
      }
```

```html
 <form oninput="x.value=parseInt(tierslider.value)">
        <span>500</span>
        <input type='range' min='500' max='10000' value='500' id='tierslider' onchange="onRangeChanged(this.value)">
        <span>10000</span>
        <output id='tierslider2' name='x'></output>
    </form>

<a href='#' id='DisplaySliderResult'>Take me to my ideal object!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the on change event as explained here:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

and then in you onchenge function do something like this:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("tierslider");
var link = document.getElementById("DisplaySliderResult");
if(myInput.value > 100) { // just an example
    link.href = "..."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript for get the right url based on the slider value. You can use `onclick` event for calling a `function`. Get the slider value, and redirect to specific url when match the condition.

Here is the code :

```
<div id='slidecontainer'>
    <form oninput="x.value=parseInt(tierslider.value)">
        <span>500</span>
        <input type='range' min='500' max='10000' value='500' id='tierslider'>
        <span>10000</span>
        <output id='tierslider2' name='x'></output>
    </form>
</div>

<a href='#' id='DisplaySliderResult' onclick='changeLink()'>Take me to my ideal object!</a>

<script>
    function changeLink() {
        var sliderValue = document.getElementById("tierslider").value;
        if(sliderValue <= 1000){
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        }
        else if(sliderValue <= 2000){
            window.location.href = "http://www.microsoft.com";
        }
        else if(sliderValue <= 4000){
            window.location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
        }
        else{
            window.location.href = "http://www.github.com";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

```js
document.getElementById('smpl').addEventListener('click', function() {

  document.getElementById('smplh').setAttribute('href', 'https://stackoverflow.com');

  document.getElementById('smplh').innerHTML = 'click to go to stackoverflow';

});
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="smplh">click to go to google</a>

<button id="smpl">click to change the hyperlink adress to stackoverflow</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach. First Create an array in javascript with the values you want. After that, when ever the slider change update the selected value in the output. Finally when you click on the link select the the value and append it to the link

```js
// Setting custom points to slider
var values = [0, 1000,2000,4000,10000];

var input = document.getElementById('tierslider'),
    output = document.getElementById('tierslider2');
    
input.oninput = function(){
    output.innerHTML = values[this.value];
};

input.oninput();

// Redirect 
function redirectToLinks(elem){
  window.location.href = elem.dataset.baselink + values[input.value];
}
```

```html
<div id='slidecontainer'>
      <form>
          <span>500</span>
          <input type='range' min='0' max='4' value="0" step="1" id='tierslider'>
          <span>10000</span>
          <span id='tierslider2'></span>
      </form>
</div>

<a href='#' data-baselink='http://www.example.com/page?param=' id='DisplaySliderResult' onclick="redirectToLinks(this)">Take me to my ideal object!</a>
```